# Query a String Using Stream Builder

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

When attempting to query, a MongoDB Document containing a KVP:

"Cell_Lon": "-105.2"

I try to use a std::string Cell_Lon variable to perform findOne query using the bson streambuilder:

```
bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> optional_value_result =
    collection.find_one(document{} << "Location.Cell_Lon" << Cell_Lon << finalize);
```

When I hardcode the Cell_Lon string to: "-105.2" the query works. I've tried adding "\"" and '\"' to each side of the string and using std::quoted to no avail.

I'm thinking there must be something in the bsoncxx library for this but can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to use a string that had double quotes. Apparently, just passing a string variable to streambuilder tells it to add the double quotes!